# How can I run a function for just 5 minutes?

Tags: python, django, scheduling

```
import logging

from a.x.models import X
from a.x.management.commands.syncx \
    import Command as SyncCommand

from a.x.adapter_classes import ADAPTER_CLASSES

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def logger_function(code):
    if not X.objects.filter(code=code).exists():
        X.objects.create(code=code)
        LOGGER.info(f"{X} created")

    args = []
    kwargs = {'x_code': code,
              'class': False,
              'database': 'default'}

    try:
        LOGGER.info(f"Starting syncx command for {code}")
        #or this command needs to be run just 5 minutes for every key
        SyncCommand().handle(*args, **kwargs)
        LOGGER.info(f"There is no error for {code}")

    except Exception as error:
        with open("logger.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(f"{code}'s error is : {error}")
            LOGGER.info(f"Logging error about {code}\n")


def run():
    for key in ADAPTER_CLASSES.keys():
        #this function needs to be run just 5 minutes for every key
        logger_function(key)
```

My logger_function needs to be run for 5 minutes. Is there any timer decorator or thread destroyer with timer ? How can I do this.
My for loop is shifting in keys and sending to logger function , if there any problem for try except block its okey , but if everything right for my SyncCommand it can take a many hours, bu i just want to logging errors in first 5 minutes.

Comment: What should happen after the 5 minutes is up? What if the logger is in the middle of doing something important when that happens?

Comment: When 5 minutes end command should stop and command must start for next key.My purpose is logging errors if working correctly in 5 minutes I am sure there is nor error about key.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there any timer decorator*

If you are allowed to use external libraries I suggest taking look at [timeout-decorator](https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/).

Answer (score 0):

```
    # importing the required module 
import timeit 
  
# code snippet to be executed only once 
mysetup = "from math import sqrt"
  
# code snippet whose execution time is to be measured 
mycode = ''' 
def example(): 
    mylist = [] 
    for x in range(100): 
        mylist.append(sqrt(x)) 
'''
  
# timeit statement 
print timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup, 
                    stmt = mycode, 
                    number = 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with using signal library

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    raise Exception(None)

#do stuff func

 for key in ADAPTER_CLASSES.keys():
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
        signal.alarm(300) #5 min
        logger_function(key)
        signal.alarm(0)
```